# QWidgets from QGridLayout that don't take up all the space

Tags: c++, qt, qlayout

I try to create a responsive QGridLayout with Qt5.
Here is the part of my function that initializes the QGridLayout.

```
std::vector< std::vector< QPushButton* > > tab2d;
// [...]
for (int i = yyy-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    for (int j {0}; j < xxx; j++)
    {
        if (tab2d[j][i] == nullptr) 
        {
            tab2d[j][i] = new QPushButton(this);
            tab2d[j][i]->setIcon(icon);
            tab2d[j][i]->setIconSize(QSize(150,150)); //);
            tab2d[j][i]->setStyleSheet("background: none");
            
            connect(tab2d[j][i], &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this , i, j]{ createNewSlide(j,i); });

        }
        else
        {
            connect(tab2d[j][i], &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this , i, j]{ button_c(j,i); });
        }
        
        grid->addWidget(tab2d[j][i],yyy-1- i, j, 1, 1);
}

grid->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
grid->setSpacing(0);
```

But the result is bad:

The buttons are not the same size

[image: The buttons are not the same size]

When I resize the window:

[image: When I resize the window]

I would like to have the same size for all buttons, and that there is no spacing when I resize the window, I would like the QGridLayout to adapt the buttons to the new window size.

I tried something with the QGridLayout::setSizeConstraint with different values but it doesn't change anything.

So can you help me to find a solution.
Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.  Is it simply that you want each button to fill the space provided for it by the layout?  If so you might want to try something like `tab2d[j][i]->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred)` where `tab2d[j][i]` is the `QPushButton *` of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you again G.M.

The solution is to use `setSizePolicy` with

```
tab2d[j][i]->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
```

It's work